# Nao consigo salvar no banco e nem mostra log de erro no projeto hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, jsf, hibernate, jpa

No projeto utilizo `hibernate`, e quando tento salvar um novo cliente, apenas mostra a mensagem de validacao da classe `CadastroClienteService`. O estranho é que todos os campos são preenchidos no form, parece `null pointer`, mas não identifiquei aonde está apresentando o erro. Se alguem identificar, agradeço de antemao a força.

-> Estas são as classes do projeto:

> Classe Cliente

```
package com.tacocell.controleservicos.model;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.persistence.Column;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
import javax.persistence.Id;
import javax.persistence.Table;
import javax.persistence.Temporal;
import javax.persistence.TemporalType;



@Entity
@Table(name = "clientes")
public class Cliente implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Long codigo;
    private String nomeCliente;
    private String cnpj;
    private String cpf;
    private String endereco;
    private String bairro;
    private int cep;
    private String telefoneFixo;
    private String telefoneCel;
    private String email;
    private Date dataCadastro;


    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    public Long getCodigo() {
        return codigo;
    }

    public void setCodigo(Long codigo) {
        this.codigo = codigo;
    }

    @Column(name="nm_cli")
    public String getNomeCliente() {
        return nomeCliente;
    }

    public void setNomeCliente(String ncliente) {
        this.nomeCliente = ncliente;
    }

    public String getCnpj() {
        return cnpj;
    }

    public void setCnpj(String cnpj) {
        this.cnpj = cnpj;
    }

    public String getCpf() {
        return cpf;
    }

    public void setCpf(String cpf) {
        this.cpf = cpf;
    }

    public String getEndereco() {
        return endereco;
    }

    public void setEndereco(String endereco) {
        this.endereco = endereco;
    }

    public String getBairro() {
        return bairro;
    }

    public void setBairro(String bairro) {
        this.bairro = bairro;
    }

    public int getCep() {
        return cep;
    }

    public void setCep(int cep) {
        this.cep = cep;
    }

    @Column(name="telfixo")
    public String getTelefoneFixo() {
        return telefoneFixo;
    }

    public void setTelefoneFixo(String telefoneFixo) {
        this.telefoneFixo = telefoneFixo;
    }

    @Column(name="telcel")
    public String getTelefoneCel() {
        return telefoneCel;
    }

    public void setTelefoneCel(String telefoneCel) {
        this.telefoneCel = telefoneCel;
    }

    public String getEmail() {
        return email;
    }

    public void setEmail(String email) {
        this.email = email;
    }

    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name="dt_cad")
    public Date getDataCadastro() {
        return dataCadastro;
    }

    public void setDataCadastro(Date dataCadastro) {
        this.dataCadastro = dataCadastro;
    }


    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((codigo == null) ? 0 : codigo.hashCode());
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Cliente other = (Cliente) obj;
        if (codigo == null) {
            if (other.codigo != null)
                return false;
        } else if (!codigo.equals(other.codigo))
            return false;
        return true;
    }

}
```

> Classe CadastroClienteBean

```
package com.tacocell.controleservicos.controller;

import java.io.Serializable;

import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;
import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.inject.Named;

import com.tacocell.controleservicos.util.jsf.FacesUtil;
import com.tacocell.controleservicos.model.Cliente;
import com.tacocell.controleservicos.service.CadastroClienteService;
import com.tacocell.controleservicos.service.NegocioException;

@Named
@ViewScoped
public class CadastroClienteBean implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    private Cliente cliente;

    @Inject
    private CadastroClienteService cadastroClienteService;

    public CadastroClienteBean(){
        limpar();
    }

    public void salvar()  {
        try{
            this.cadastroClienteService.salvar(cliente);
            FacesUtil.addSuccessMessage("Cliente salvo com sucesso!");          
        }catch(NegocioException ne) {
            FacesUtil.addErrorMessage(ne.getMessage());
        }

        limpar();
    }

    public void limpar() {
        this.cliente = new Cliente();       
    }

    public Cliente getCliente() {
        return cliente;
    }

    public void setCliente(Cliente cliente) {
        this.cliente = cliente;
    }

}
```

> Classe ClienteDAO

```
package com.tacocell.controleservicos.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.List;

import javax.inject.Inject;
import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

import org.hibernate.Criteria;
import org.hibernate.Session;
import org.hibernate.criterion.MatchMode;
import org.hibernate.criterion.Restrictions;

import com.tacocell.controleservicos.model.Cliente;

public class ClienteDAO implements Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private EntityManager manager;

    public void salvar(Cliente cliente) {
        manager.merge(cliente);
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<Cliente> filtrar(Cliente cliente){
        Session session = manager.unwrap(Session.class);
        Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Cliente.class);

        if (cliente.getNomeCliente() != null && !cliente.getNomeCliente().trim().equals("")) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("nm_cli", cliente.getNomeCliente(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
        }

        if (cliente.getCnpj() != null && !cliente.getCnpj().trim().equals("")) {
            criteria.add(Restrictions.ilike("cnpj", cliente.getCnpj(), MatchMode.ANYWHERE));
        }

        return criteria.list();

    }
    public Cliente buscarPeloCodigo(Long codigo) {
        return manager.find(Cliente.class, codigo);
    }
}
```

> Classe CadastroClienteService

```
package com.tacocell.controleservicos.service;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.util.Date;

import javax.inject.Inject;

import com.tacocell.controleservicos.dao.ClienteDAO;
import com.tacocell.controleservicos.model.Cliente;
import com.tacocell.controleservicos.util.jpa.Transactional;

public class CadastroClienteService implements Serializable  {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Inject
    private ClienteDAO clienteDAO;

    @Transactional
    public void salvar(Cliente cliente) throws NegocioException {


        if (cliente.getNomeCliente() == null || cliente.getNomeCliente().trim().equals("")) {
            throw new NegocioException("Este campo é obrigatório. Preencha o nome do cliente");
        }
        /*
        if (cliente.getCnpj() == null || cliente.getCnpj().trim().equals("")) {
            throw new NegocioException("O cnpj do cliente e obrigatorio");
        }
        */

        if (cliente.getCodigo() == null)
        {
            cliente.setDataCadastro(new Date());
        }

        this.clienteDAO.salvar(cliente);
    }

}
```

Comment: Pode adicionar a pilha de erro onde você viu o "null pointer" ?

Comment: Por que assim, esse código estou baseando no curso que estou fazendo, e fiz algumas adaptações para este exemplo, e já não tenho suporte ao curso para duvidas. Consultei um amigo e ele disse que poderia ser este erro, "NULL POINTER".

Comment: Não aparece no log nenhuma mensagem de erro

Comment: Então como você afirma na pergunta: *"(...)parece null pointer(...)""? Onde você viu esse null pointer? Veja no console se estoura algum erro quando você executa. Cole aqui o erro que aparecer.

Comment: Na classe CadastroClienteService no método salvar, a mensagem de erro que é gerada quando a exceção é capturada. é este erro que aparece.Em relação ao pointer null, em outro forum tive essa sugestão que poderia ser isso.

Answer (score 1):

Pelo que vi, você não inicia a classe Cliente em nenhum momento.

Tente dar um Cliente cliente = new Cliente() no seu método Salvar antes de fazer o preenchimento da classe.

Se é que este é seu problema de nullPointer.

Comment: Fiz a alteração, mas continua com o erro

Comment: Se você conseguir postar o log de erros fica melhor de visualizar o problema.

Comment: VC reparou na linha 40 da classe CadastroClienteBean